# How to redirect a packet to localhost in pf?

Tags: firewall, redirect, freebsd, nat, pf

I am trying to redirect packets that are going to internal network to localhost of firewall.

I wrote this rule but it doesn't work.

```
int_net = "{10.0.0.0/24}"
ext_if = "{igb0}"
int_if = "{igb1}"

rdr on $ext_if proto tcp from any to $int_net port www -> 127.0.0.1 port 9999
```

When I wrote 10.0.0.2 on browser, It should get a test page from firewall. But as far as I couldn't do that.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you also want "pass" here:

rdr **pass** on $ext_if proto tcp from any to $int_net port www -> 127.0.0.1 port 9999

Comment: Is there any way to make the mapping work for connections from localhost as well?